# Need to find out if particular folder exists on the server..if yes then which drive C: or D

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I need to find out if folder named `Backupeventlog` exists on the server. If yes then which drive C: or D: drive. Also is this folder empty and if not empty what is the date of latest file that has been created under this folder.

Below is the script that I was working, but it doesn't seem to work. :(

```
$a = Get-Content C:\Lists\Servers.txt
foreach ($Servers in $a)
{
    if (Test-Connection $Servers -Count 1 -ea 0 -Quiet)
    {            
        if ("Test-Path \\$Servers\D$\Backupeventlog\*" -or "Test-Path \\$Servers\C$\Backupeventlog\*")
        { 
            $latest  = Get-ChildItem \\$Servers\C$\Backupeventlog -Force |
                       Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending |
                       Select-Object -First 1
            Write-Host $Servers - Backupeventlog exists in C: drive and latest file in folder is of date $latest.Lastwritetime
            $latest1 = Get-ChildItem \\$Servers\D$\Backupeventlog -Force |
                       Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending |
                       Select-Object -First 1
            Write-Host $Servers - Backupeventlog exists in D: drive and latest file in folder is of date $latest1.Lastwritetime
        }
        else
        {
            Write-Host $Servers - Backupevent folder does not exist or empty
        }
    }
    Else
    {
        Write-Host $Servers - not pinging.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do individual checks, and don't put the entire command in double quotes (otherwise PowerShell will just echo the command string without actually executing the command):

```
if (Test-Path \\$Servers\C$\Backupeventlog\*) {
  $latest = Get-ChildItem \\$Servers\C$\Backupeventlog -Force |
            Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending |
            Select-Object -First 1
  Write-Host 'drive C:'
} elseif (Test-Path \\$Servers\D$\Backupeventlog\*) {
  $latest = Get-ChildItem \\$Servers\D$\Backupeventlog -Force |
            Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending |
            Select-Object -First 1
  Write-Host 'drive D:'
} else {
  Write-Host 'not found'
}
```

If the backup folder can only exist on one of the drives and you can neglect information about servers that have neither you could also do a pipeline like this to get just the latest file from each server where the backup folder exists:

```
Get-Content C:\Lists\Servers.txt |
  Where-Object { Test-Connection $_ -Count 1 -Quiet } |
  ForEach-Object {
    Get-ChildItem "\\$_\C$\Backupeventlog\*", "\\$_\D$\Backupeventlog\*" -EA SilentlyContinue |
      Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending |
      Select-Object -First 1 -Expand FullName
  }
```

Since the full path still contains the drive information you can extract the drive letter later if required.